# How recive data from SQL Server to Android Application, in autonomous manner?

Tags: android, sql-server, database, web-services, auto-update

I have created a web service which, querying a SQL Server, retrives several tables.
I'm consuming this web service using KSoap2 package in Android application, and  I want maintain alligned the tables on SQL Server and tables on Android Application.
Many of the tables in SQL Server remain the same over time, but some others change frequently. I need an automatic mechanism for update the tables on Android Application, on the initiative of Server. 
I think I need a socket on Android application, for listening a signal transmitted from SQL Server, the meaning of which is "the data in some tables are changed". So, then, I can use the web service call for retrieves new data.
Is this possible? anyone has suggestions?

Comment: maybe not the best solution but ... you can try [Ms Sync Framework](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/silverlight/Sync-Framework-Toolkit-4dc10f0e) and [my Android implementation](http://selvinlistsyncsample.codeplex.com/) ... you can also use [GCM](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/index.html) to inform your application that data have change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer for you question is a [Android Service class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html). It can sit behind the program and listen to changes going on your SQL server and update it in SQLite database (or whatever you have)